Set up Structured logging in cloud composer
I am trying to implement a custom logging format which includes a few variables which I get from the Google Cloud Composer environment, I have followed the docs which helped me in formatting the required environment variables by overriding the airflow.cfg logging_config_class variable. However, the composer restricts the modification of that logging class.Is there any other way to have a custom logger?
I want to be able to send a jsonPayload into google cloud which I can query. I have even tried using python gcloud loggers as follows:
from google.cloud import logging as gcloud_logging
LOG_NAME = 'airflow-worker'
client = gcloud_logging.Client()

gcloud_logger = client.logger(LOG_NAME)


gcloud_logger.log_struct({
            "message": "message text to appear in StackDriver",
            "custom_key": "value"
        }, severity='ERROR')

I followed this answer too but did not help. All these logs just show up as textPayload on gcs.

Your approach is correct. I don't use Cloud Composer but a trivial repro of your code produced a structured (jsonPayload) log entry for me. Does using stdout instead of airflow-worker make a difference?

What is your airflow.cfg for log structures?

I don't use Cloud Composer (Airflow) but am familiar with structured logging and wrote a (Golang) package to implement it for a solution. Cloud Composer uses GKE which is what I use too for structured logging.

Google cloud composer has no support for this as of today

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
